# JSF Obtaining value from one managed bean to another as argument

Tags: java, jsf, el, facelets

I've just created a Login Managed Bean and works perfectly. It takes the value of email and password.

Now, my problem is how to pass the value of the email obtained by the **LoginBean.java** to my **UserBean.java**.

**index_customer.xhtml**

```
<h:outputText value="#{userBean.firstname}"/>
```

**UserBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="userBean")
public class UserBean {
   private static String firstname;
   private String lastname;
   private String email;
   private String password;

   public String firstname(String email){
       String fname;
       UserDAOImpl userDAOImpl = new UserDAOImpl();
       fname = userDAOImpl.getFirstName(email);
       return fname;
   }  

}
```

**LoginBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")

public class LoginBean {

    private String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

How can i call the method `getEmail()` and supply the email as argument to `UserBean`'s `firstname(email)` method?

Is this possible? The reason I asked is, I want to identify the first name of the user who logged in and show something like "Hello **YourFirstName**" using the EL expression on `<h:outputText value="#{userBean.firstname}"/>`

I worked with swing before but I know that things are different with web so I guess static variables isn't the correct way to get variable values from one class to another in JSF.

My `UserDAOImpl.getFirstName(email)` method has an SQL query which is

```
String SQL = "SELECT firstname from customer WHERE emailcolumn = email;
```

Thanks in advance. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Learn about injection. And if you are new to jsf, use cdi managed beans instead of the (sort of) deprecated jsf specific ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the return value of getEmail to firstName method as parameter.

```
<h:outputText value="#{userBean.firstname(loginBean.email)}"/>
```

But of course there are some other details.
You should keep this kind of data in a session scoped bean. And DataBase acces on every get is not so healthy.

[How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)